# Can not delete/add default route

Tags: route, huawei

I have a Raspi connected through WiFi in which I plug-in a Huawei stick I use for SMS sending. Unfortunately when doing this, it changes the routes to the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/pi/printer $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         hi.link         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         hi.link         0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
default         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth1
```

One would guess that it should be easy to remove the route, but it doesn't work:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/pi/printer $ ping hi.link
PING hi.link (192.168.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hi.link (192.168.8.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/pi/printer $ route del default via  192.168.8.0
# does NOT work, displays the usage howto
```

I can only get this working by adding an additional route:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/pi/printer $ route add default gw 10.0.2.1 wlan0
```

**Question**: how do I either prevent this hi.link route being created when the Huawei stick is plugged in respective how can I delete this route

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it as user root?

Comment: Oh damn, my fault, sorry for that! `route add default gw 10.0.2.1 wlan0` worked now nicely, but I am still not able to delete the default via 192.168.8.0 and have it in there...

Answer (score 1):

Either using the `route` command:

```
route del default gw  192.168.8.0 dev eth1
```

or better `ip` command if available:

```
ip route del default via 192.168.8.0 dev eth1
```

The `ip` command is easier to use because `add` and `del` usually accept the same syntax as printed by `show`.

Comment: I deleted as you said and it worked fine. However, from time to time, the route appears again and I keep having the same problem (I have to redo that). Any idea what could cause this?